# Cannot figure out why i'm getting a null value in calculation

Tags: java, loops, return, arguments

So essentially this is a simple loop that should add up for 10 seconds the distance fallen for an object.  When I was debugging it I saw it passed and the variables with correct values but when I entered a println statement right after the calculation in my fallingDistance method, the variable "distance" had a value of zero which I do not see how is possible. What am I missing here?

```
import java.lang.Math;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FallingDistance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    double distance =0;
        int count = 0;
        double distanceCalc = 0;
        int varTime = 0;
        while (varTime < 10) {
            varTime += 1;
            System.out.println(varTime);
            fallingDistance(varTime);
            distanceCalc += distance;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The distance travelled is " + distanceCalc + " meters.");
        }

    }

    public static double fallingDistance(int varTime) {

        double gravity = 9.8;
        double distance = Math.pow(((1 / 2) * gravity * varTime), 2);
        System.out.println(gravity);
        return distance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your function return value but you do not using it, the `distance` in main is still 0. Edit code to this: `distance = fallingDistance(varTime);`

Comment: okay i see what you mean let me try that

Comment: oddly enough that System.out.println(gravity); at the end of the method outputs a 0.0, so you were right yet it still seems to be zero either way.

Comment: the `distance` variable in `main` is not the same as the one in `fallingDistance` despite having the same name

Comment: I meant I changed the println to print the distance after the calculation and it was a zero.  Not sure if the (1/2) is run as an integer and perhaps might be represented as a zero?

Comment: well `(1/2)` is zero. Try `1.0 / 2` or just `0.5`

Comment: YES it worked!!!  Now I guess I need to figure out my physics b/c I followed what it said in my book, but I guess there's something else to factor here.  Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: I believe only time is squared, 1/2*g is not (and I would use t*t instead of power...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please assign the value returned from `fallingDistance(varTime)` method to `distance`.

Your while loop should be rewritten as:

```
while (varTime < 10) {
    varTime += 1;
    System.out.println(varTime);
    distance = fallingDistance(varTime);
    distanceCalc += distance;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The distance travelled is " + distanceCalc + " meters.");
}
```

Also, your 1/2 will always be evaluated to 0 (because its evaluated as integer). The `fallingDistance()` method should be rewritten as:

```
public static double fallingDistance(int varTime) {

    double gravity = 9.8;
    double distance = Math.pow((0.5 * gravity * varTime), 2);
    System.out.println(gravity);
    return distance;
}
```

Comment: Ive done that, still nothing.  What I keep noticing is I changed the println at the bottom of method to print the distance variable after the calculation, and it is zero, therefor I think its returning a null value to the loop.

Comment: @XERO40 Updated my answer. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You must assign value to the `distance` before using it in main!

```
public class FallingDistance {

public static void main(String[] args) {
double distance =0;
    int count = 0;
    double distanceCalc = 0;
    int varTime = 0;
    while (varTime < 10) {
        varTime += 1;
        System.out.println(varTime);
        distance = fallingDistance(varTime);
        distanceCalc += distance;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The distance travelled is " + distanceCalc + " meters.");
    }

}

public static double fallingDistance(int varTime) {

    double gravity = 9.8;
    double distance = Math.pow(((double)(1 / 2) * gravity * varTime), 2);
    System.out.println(gravity);
    return distance;
}
```

Comment: This solution would still give results as `0` as `1/2` is an `integer` and will be evaluated to `0`.

Comment: Thanks @KrishnaKuntala, First time I just see the owner doesn't assign value